# how to understand hac_handle and hca_object of linux rdma cgroup?

Tags: cgroups, rdma

I have been conducting research on rdma cgroup recently and have found that some parameters are not well understood

The Linux Kernel documentation:

> Following resources can be accounted by rdma controller.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| hca_handle | Maximum number of HCA Handles |
| hca_object | Maximum number of HCA Objects |

I want to know what role hca_handle and hca_object play in configuring RDMA cgroup，Can you provide an example to illustrate this. Thanks